# There is no visa centre for Spain in my home city, can I apply to France instead?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, spain

I am travelling to Barcelona for a conference for 4 days but also spending 5, 2, 1 days at Paris, Madrid and Lisbon with my entry and exit point (to India) being Paris. The problem is that Spain does not have a visa centre where I live and I would have to travel far (and expensively) whereas France has a visa centre in my city.

I know 'technically' the right visa to get is from Spain but I would like to know if it is OK to apply to France (with a visa centre closer to home) since the number of days in France and Spain are almost identical and entry/exit is from France, even though the main event I am attending is in Spain.

Will it be a problem to obtain the visa at the France visa centre or will I get denied entry at Paris, since my main event is in Barcelona?

Need to apply quick.

Comment: Usually this is allowed only if the country you want to travel to has no consulate anywhere in your whole country.

Comment: Obviously I am going to state the work at Spain but more number of days is (or can be modified now) spent in Paris. So then according to rule "if the visit includes more than one destination, the Member State whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length or purpose of stay" Since Paris is the longest I am going to stay in (in the modified plan), France application will be fine now?

Answer (score 4):

In theory, if the purpose of your trip is a conference in Spain, then Spain is your main destination regardless of how many days you spend in France.  However, it is most common to judge the main destination by the number of days spent in each country.  Therefore, the French consulate may accept or reject your application depending on how much weight they give to the conference.

If the French authorities decide that Spain is your main destination, they are supposed to return your application along with the visa fee and instructions to seek the visa from Spain (I do not know whether they will return the processing fee).  The costs of a rejected application, therefore, are relatively low.

Your best course of action, therefore, is probably to modify your itinerary so that you are spending more days in France than in Spain, but be aware that it's possible you'll still have to apply to Spain in the end.

If you do not have time for a second application, then the more certain course of action would be to apply to Spain.

Comment: After reading the answers I am planning on modifying the itinerary and making Paris the most days stayed while disclosing about the conference  and my intended trip to Lisbon in the French visa application.

Answer (score 2):

It seems we know the essential purpose of your trip is the conference in Barcelona. If that is so it determines where you are supposed to apply - ie Spanish visa centre, regardless of how long you spend in other countries.

From Article V of     [REGULATION   (EC)   No   810/2009   OF   THE   EUROPEAN   PARLIAMENT   AND   OF   THE COUNCIL
of  13  July  2009
establishing  a  Community  Code  on  Visas
(Visa  Code)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2009R0810:20160412:EN:PDF):

> 1. The      Member      State      competent      for      examining      and      deciding      on      an       application 
>      for  a  uniform  visa  shall  be:
>
> (a)  the  Member  State  whose 
>   territory  constitutes  the  sole  destination  of   the  visit(s);
>
> (b)  if  the  visit  includes  more  than  one  destination,  the 
>   Member  State   whose  territory  constitutes  the  main  destination 
>   of  the  visit(s)  in   terms  of  the  length  or  purpose  of  stay;
>   or
>
> (c)  if  no  main  destination  can  be  determined,  the  Member 
>   State  whose   external  border  the  applicant  intends  to  cross 
>   in  order  to  enter  the   territory  of  the  Member  States.

Attending the conference is good reason for making the trip. Mention of it strengthens your application and can be expected to improve your chances of being granted a visa (by Spain).

Balance the days in France and Spain and neglect to mention (unless asked, of course!) the conference and France should not refuse (decline to consider) your application on the grounds that you have applied to the wrong visa centre. France would be *the  Member State  whose   external  border  the  applicant  intends  to  cross in  order  to  enter  the   territory  of  the  Member  States*.

Go a step further and arrange more days in France than in Spain (or anywhere else Schengen) and France should still not refuse your application since it would be *the Member State whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length ... of stay*.

However, if France finds out about the conference it might decide for itself that that is the real ('main') purpose for your trip and, for failing to declare it, reject your application under 8. *the information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable* (same link, page 55).

It is up to you to weigh the risk of not obtaining a visa, in time, from either centre (and the possibility of a black mark against you) against the cost/inconvenience. That may sound bleak but if, say, you are very confident France would issue you a visa were there no conference involved at all (for example, there are **no** doubts about itinerary, subsistence, insurance) it could be a risk worth taking. For example, if this is not the first time you have applied for a Schengen visa and have never been refused any visa.

The risk is not so much that you may be denied entry at Paris but that France won't issue you a visa.

Comment: A rejected application should not result in a black mark; it's not the same as a refused application.  If a Schengen consulate decides that it is not competent to consider the application, it does not consider the application.

Comment: Would France be more likely to choose 8 than Spain?  They're supposed to judge whether they're competent before considering the purpose and conditions of intended stay.  Granted, they might not follow the procedure correctly, but if they do, and if they determine that the main destination is Spain, they cannot refuse the visa, only reject the application.

Comment: Sure, applying without mentioning the conference risks refusal for fraud and would be a risky thing to do.  If France refuses for that reason, Spain is unlikely to grant a subsequent visa.

Answer (score -3):

If you planning to visit two or more Schengen countries, you should apply for the visa in the embassy/consulate of the country you will be residing in for most of the traveling days, so you have all rights to apply for a visa in France Embassy since you planing to be 5 days in France, but purpose of visit of course can't be conference in Spain. 
Just apply for tourist visa in France and provide a proof of accommodation in France for your entire stay in Schengen area, then travel to Spain on conference and other countries. Nobody will cause you problems, becuase with your Schengen visa you have right to travel to other countries in Schengen area.

Comment: I can modify my plan to have Paris more then! Now French application should be fine?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I overlooked 2 days in Madrid, but if he provides poof of accommodation in France for his entire stay in Schengen area nobody will ask him why he stayed 6 days in Spain and 5 days in France because nobody can know his intentions. Plans can be changed during your trip, he will not brake any law if he stay one day longer in some other country.

Comment: Yes Ram Kumar, if you modify your plan just for one day you have every right to apply for a visa in France Embassy.

Comment: "proof of accommodation in France for his entire stay in the Schengen area" would be fraud, since he is not planning to spend his entire stay in the Schengen area.  Fraud is very risky.

Comment: @phoog Did you ever applied for Schengen visa? Are you in business that is somehow related to this area? Do you know what is exactly proof of accommodation? Are you here just to collect badges or you want to help others? Man have the problem and you are talking about things that are not familiar to you. Proof of accommodation is just proof that you have where to stay while you in France. It can be even longer than your stay in Schengen area. How that is fraud?

Comment: @pnuts I see in your answers here and on other places that you don't have any legal knowledge or experience regarding to this area. You just googling the information and paste it here. You misleading people often. Maybe you are not completely aware of that, but that does not excuse you. People can have troubles just because you chasing reputation points. I'm in business closely related to this area for years and I can't believe what you said to people all over this website. I'm new here and I don't know how this platform works, but I hope that we can report such behavior.

Comment: @Puzzler it is fraud if you show that you will be staying in France for the entire time, for example through a hotel reservation, when you in fact intend to travel to another country.  People have been denied visas for less, and they have been denied entry into the Schengen area for changing their travel plans after their visa applications; there are questions on this site that show as much.  One thing you should learn about this site is that there is a policy of [being nice](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which means you should refrain from ad hominem rhetoric.

Comment: @phong Do you really understand what is ad hominem? I asked you do you know what is the proof of accommodation and explained why I'm asking that? Proof of accommodation is not guarantee that you will be on one place during your entire stay and your are not obligated to be on that place your entire stay. You do have rights to visit Spain or any other country with Schengen visa, but if you change your plans and decide not to visit the Spain you will have accommodation during your entire stay.

Comment: @phong  Having accommodation in France during his entire stay even if he will be few days in Spain it's not fraud, it's a bonus. It's like having a more money than you need or having a travel insurance with 50.000 EUR coverage instead of 30.000 EUR. 
Please don't "ad hominem" me, you missing the point all the time. I don't know anything about other examples that you mentioned and you didn't proved anything with that statement, so give me just ONE example that will prove that I'm not telling the truth.

Comment: @phoog definitely understands all this, do you? If the OP mentions the fact he will be going to a conference in Spain, accommodation in France is irrelevant and does not solve his problem. If he doesn't and tries to suggest he is only visiting the Schengen area to spend time in France, then he would be committing fraud by misrepresenting his intent. It's indeed possible to change your plans but that's not what we are talking about here, the OP is *already* planning to go to Spain. There is no way around that, the rest is irrelevant.